# Lua map value as constructor

Tags: arrays, dictionary, constructor, lua

I want to store my constructors in map so that I get create object i.e in foreach for different defined types

Something like this

```
ObjByType = { "integer" = IntegerObj, "float" = FloatObj }
x = ObjByType["integer"]( arg1, arg2, arg3 )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this syntax:

```
ObjByType = { integer = IntegerObj, float = FloatObj }
```

or this one if the fields are not simple words:

```
ObjByType = { ["integer"] = IntegerObj, ["float"] = FloatObj }
```